# How many server blocks can I add in Nginx Conf?

Tags: nginx, server, sni, server-name

I found this question
[How many server blocks can I add in Nginx Conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910846/how-many-server-blocks-can-i-add-in-nginx-conf)

But I don't think adjust server_names_hash_bucket_size and server_names_hash_max_size is the answer.

Because the explanation from Nginx is this:

If a large number of server names are defined, or unusually long server names are defined, tuning the server_names_hash_max_size and server_names_hash_bucket_size directives at the http level may become necessary.

Which means changing this 2 values will only solve the issue of having large number of server names but not the sever blocks.

In my case, I will have to create 10000 of server block and each block has one server name.

Anyone knows if there is a maximum number on how many server blocks that I can create?